Point defense weapons on bio-mechanical spacecraft that part of von Neumann machine horde
I am currently working on a concept for a science fiction novel about interstellar warfare in the 24th century.
I am wondering about the best point defense weapons for biomechanical space combat ships that part of biomechanical von Neumann machine horde that threatens all intelligent species.
They are composed of advanced biomaterials that can be called nanobots of some sort but  the ship contains some mechanical structures like reactors and thrusters.
They are slightly similar to the Thargoid ships in Elite Dangerous.
I decided that those ships would fire "swarm missile" as primary weapon, but I thought they still lacked point defense weapons.
What kind of point defense weapon would be best?
DEWs like neutral particle beam weapons, or KEWs like gauss cannon?
Edit: These ships will primarily face missile saturation attacks flying from thousands of kilometers away, which is why they need point defense.
(The human fleets that opposes them in this world uses primarily kinetic missiles in engagements, and railguns and autocannons at close range.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe I don't undestand, since I am unaware of what an Dangerous Elite Thargoid is, but in my mind the entire point of a von Neumann swarm is that the swarm itself is the first-class entity, and the role of point defense weapons would be taken by some of the ships. The whole ship is a point defense weapon, or  a long range weapon, or a scout, or a resource gatherer and so on. (BTW, if there are Dangerous Elite Thargoids, should one assume that there are also Tame Ordinary Thargoids?)

@AlexP how could you possibly interpret "the Thargoid ships in Elite Dangerous" as meaning "Dangerous Elite Thargoids"?

@MS: A general officer in the 7th Cavalry is a 7th Cavalry General. An A-10 Thunderbolt II aircraft in the 514th Flight Test Squadron is a Test Squadron A-10 Thunderboldt II. A Prevost bus of the Greyhound Lines is a Greyhound Lines Prevost. In general, <a $CLASSNAME $GENERICNAME in $GROUPNAME> is <a $GROUPNAME $CLASSNAME>.

This lacks details on the available tech, which will be important in any answer.

OP - Point defense is primarily a function of what the expected threat is going to be. Kinetic projectiles, Chemical and explosive warheads, Lasers etc. We need to know what sort of weaponary your ship(s) are facing so we can make some good suggesgtions.

Several questions. How much does the humans armor their missiles? if they do, then how effective are these armors? after that, how long do the point defence have to attempt to shoot them?

Missiles have almost no armor.
Direct hit from one or two autocannon rounds could destroy it. Instead, missiles try to dodge fire with RCS thrusters when they enter the terminal phase.

@Akifumi121 about how big is one missile? I was assuming something the size of a sidewinder but then realised that it's a assumption and you didn't say that

@General_Ripper It's about 5 meters to 6 meters long. The shape is not that fat


These ships will primarily face missile saturation attacks flying from thousands of kilometers away, which is why they need point defense

I'll take this as the design constraint. An enemy shoots chemical rocket powered missiles at your ship from a few thousand km away in space. The enemy is stationary with respect to you. You want to stop them using realistic technology, before the missiles hit.
Here are your main choices:

Railguns or equivalent
Lasers
Particle beams
Interceptor rockets


Railguns
The advantage of railguns is relatively cheap ammunition. One shot costing a few thousand dollars can blow up an incoming missile worth hundreds of millions of dollars.
The disadvantage of railguns is that at distances of a few hundred km, the enemy rocket can dodge. If the rocket is moving at 10 km/s, and your railgun round is also moving at 10 km/s, then at 100 km the rocket has five seconds to get out of the way. At 10 km the rocket has half a second to get out of the way - which could be possible - and it also hits in one second. (Or possibly it could detonate at 10 km distance already, if it has a nuclear warhead.)

Lasers
Each laser shot is cheap, and the light also travels to the target very quickly. At distances under a thousand km, the rocket has only a few ms to get out of the way. Dodging is probably not very feasible.
The challenge of lasers is twofold. First, lasers spread out over long distances. It is very difficult to focus the beam to a small point thousands of km away. You need a very large lens and a very highly coherent beam. No military laser in use today can do anything like that.
Second, lasers just don't do that much damage. If the missile moves at 10 km/s across 1000 km of distance, you have 100 seconds to burn through its frontal armor and destroy it. The missile might have very thick frontal armor, perhaps a meter or two thick, and in addition it can be spinning and weaving side to side so that you can't keep the laser focused on a single point. So you can't burn a small hole - you have to vaporize basically all of the frontal armor in order to destroy the missile.
So you're looking at a very, very big laser with a large power plant. Say that the missile's frontal armor is a chunk of steel 1m x 1m x 2m. This will take around 120 GJ of energy to vaporize. If the laser is 5% efficient at delivering power to the target, you need a 20 GW laser to destroy the missile in time, equivalent to the full power generation capacity of the largest power plant in the world, the Three Gorges Dam. And that's just for one missile, when the enemy could launch a hundred at once!
There are also laser countermeasures the enemy can use. He can use highly reflective armor that is steeply slanted, so that your laser energy is dispersed over a large area and reflected away, which may reduce the intensity below the threshold needed to melt the target at all. This can be overcome with a large enough laser, but we're already talking very big lasers.
The laser does, however, make it challenging for the incoming missile to see you. Any forward-facing camera would be destroyed immediately. This makes it harder for the incoming missile to avoid railgun rounds or interceptors.

Particle beams
These run into similar problems as lasers. A particle beam hit is not going to punch through a couple meters of steel, because the particle is not very massive, even though it may have lots of energy. So to get through the armor, you're going to have to just vaporize all of it. That's going to require a vast power plant and a really big gun - multiplied by the number of enemy missiles in the volley.
The one advantage a particle beam has over a laser is that it might be accurately aimed over long distances without needing a huge lens. Note that really big lenses are not only heavy and expensive, they're prime targets for enemy lasers - the enemy could focus on a single point on the lens and crack it. So a particle beam could be harder for the enemy to shut down.

Interceptor rockets
These will probably work and are the main way that we shoot down incoming missiles on present-day Earth. The main concern here is that you want the interceptor to be cheaper than the incoming enemy missile.
You can build the interceptors to be nimble and a bit smaller than the incoming missiles. They also don't need to have a very high delta-V; it's okay if they only approach the enemy at 2 km/s while the enemy missile approaches at 10 km/s, because if they meet the enemy missile 100 km away, that's fine. The important thing is that they can maneuver laterally faster than the enemy missile.
The interceptors probably cannot expect to score a direct physical hit on the frontal armor of the enemy missile. The enemy can juke sideways very sharply in a random direction in the very instant before impact, allowing the interceptor no time to react and match them. The interceptor instead should be equipped with explosive (perhaps nuclear) to damage the thinner side armor of the enemy missile as they pass each other closely.

So I would recommend using interceptor rockets, plus dazzler lasers to make it harder for the enemy rockets to dodge your interceptors, with railguns to destroy missiles only at very short ranges <10 km so the missiles do not have time to dodge.

Some suspicion regarding points made here: you have mentioned lasers as relying on melting the target for damage, which might not be the only method available. according to atomic rockets by pulsing a laser it can do much more damage by creating craters (https://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacewardefense.php), with this method the 20GW pulsed laser could blast through 2m^3 of steel within about 1/13th of a second. Secondly particle beams could also damage their target by radiation which might do interesting things to their electronics (I have no equation for that though)

@General_Ripper I have looked into how pulsed lasers work for laser cutting, and generally they still need to vaporize about 10% of the material (to produce the concussive force to eject the other 90%). So under ideal conditions that's only a 10x speedup (from 100 seconds). 1/13 of a second? Bullshit. projectrho has a lot of dubious stuff. Also, a pulsed laser requires enough time for the solid material to get ejected before the next pulse arrives, which limits the rate it can cut. And it's dubious that you could maintain coherent microsecond pulses through the size of lens needed.

@General_Ripper Here, take a look at https://artizono.com/ipg-laser-cutting-table/ . I think the most relevant entry is the 8000W cutter in SS(N2) (that's stainless steel under nitrogen gas), at 30 mm depth. (Ideally it would be under vacuum but at least N2 is inert) For 30mm steel, at 8000 OUTPUT watts, the laser cuts 0.2 m/min. The cut width is not in that table but other sources say that a cut width might be around 0.001 inches ( 0.0254 mm). So plug that into Wolfram Alpha

And we find that a 20 GW OUTPUT laser would cut at a staggering 23 cubic meters per hour. Not exactly combat-ready! Cut that rate by 50%-70% because the output wattage is less than the input wattage. (Note: 8000W at 30mm depth was chosen because it is the max wattage in the table at the max depth)

It's possible the cut width is closer to 1 mm than 0.0254 mm, which would mean the 20 GW output laser would cut 15 m^3/min (and really more like 5-10 m^3/min for a 20 GW input wattage). Still nowhere near your claim of 2 m^3 in 1/13 of a second.

I see, thanks for the correction, I'll go fix my own answer in accordance to this

@General_Ripper Also if you try to dump 20 GW of power into the steel block it's going to instantly create a big cloud of iron gas in front of the armor, and your laser is then going to waste most of its energy heating up that cloud. Laser blooming.

Biologic, eh.. i would go with growing diamond darts.At the rear a chamber that contains some pretty energy intensive reaction to propel the dart further. If they can marshal the chemistry, they could synthesize almost anything and they are in space already. So, the weight is negligible. Just one chamber with heavy water ice, surrounding fine strands of whatever metal you can get ignite. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Energy-density-and-specific-energy-of-various-metal-fuels-compared-to-hydrocarbons_fig2_327372687
You could pop these darts from a organically grown canon, but that is not very biotech. You could also propel them with a sequence of mantis legs on mantis legs. https://pateklab.biology.duke.edu/research/mechanics-of-ultrafast-movement/mechanics-of-movement-mantis-shrimp/
Very cool throwing mechanism, in danger of flinging itself apart though.
Finally consider the damage- you have bioships, advanced bioships. They could send a little lab flying, analyze the impacted site and then start growing something cool from that energy rich slab of metal with screaming passengers in it. The infection could also be "stealthy" as in, while it grows it mimicry whatever its replacing. So for a brief moment, you have a battle cruiser - which is all clanky martial metal, touchscreens and comfy chairs- who brief a sigh of relief, when the "hosts" don't realize the torpedo bay has been eaten and the sailor reporting is glued to some bio wall of horrors.

So you mean it's kind of "shard cannon" that fires self-propelled projectile? It's exotic and interesting

Slings, as in its a mechanical sling that throws them the first mile, before the burn chamber is ignited. Hope it fits into the world. Also remember to not go for "analogs" of our mechanical devices. Its biological, it can do wild things..  Throw a million spores into your systems Oort cloud, growing into launchers, firing at all in-system traffic. The limitations of humanity do not apply.

Another idea is- to have point defenses, that come off the ship. As in you fire at them. And it turns out the whole thing is basically a self-sufficient little "turret in space" attached to a caprice that can be shed like snake skin. Like, you attack a ton of ships drifting, the points fight back. And its all just empty "sheds", while the actual ship sneaked off a long time ago.

While we are at it. Another interesting angle would be almost zero weight projectiles. Just one long, hair thin strand of diamond, accelerated to spin at ridiculous rotational speeds. If it hits, the strand breaks of, all that energy, gets transferred into the local surrounding material. And then the next part of the strand slams into it. Again and again.

Causative concluded most of the options that I was going to suggest even though I don't agree with some of his points, here's some more options:
Kinetic Drones
Whipple shields are great for stopping kinetic rounds, but if the incoming round have a sufficiently high kinetic energy than you might need more space than you could afford with pylons. Thus, you may want to have a swarm of drones each carrying a whipple shield on them, and use them to ram incoming missile. This way you could easily have a detonation distance measured in kilometers, which makes it extremely hard for kinetic rounds to scratch your hull if detonated this way. They are primarily different from interceptor rockets in that they are constantly outside the vessel's hull, which means that they could theoretically build up their numbers around the expected direction of a missile attack and respond faster than interceptor missiles
Laser, really big lasers
It is mentioned that the von newmann fleet uses missiles themselves, but it's obviously problematic if much of your missile is fuel and only a tiny portion actually strikes the target. Thus, how about using the launching mothership to mount a massive laser and give your own missile a boost with laser thermal propulsion? [it's exhaust velocity can be much higher than what's possible with even metallic hydrogen][1], meaning that your missile can have less propellant and more mass to hit the enemy with, electronics, RCS and others. You do have to limit the ability to focus the laser though, because otherwise it raises the question of why don't the von newmann fleet just shoot the humans with the laser. The part that's relavent to your question is that, if there's a massive laser used to boost friendly missiles, then there's no reason why can't it also act as a very powerful point defence weapon that coud be expected to vaporise most incoming missiles from the front. It also helps with making a more interesting space battle, as the human commanders would have to try to anticipate where the laser is pointing, and try to avoid sending their missiles into the laser's firing arc.
Particle Beams
The reasoning behind having particle beams shoot incoming missiles is very similar to the laser above, however it is more complicated than simply melting the target. Particle beams could be used to fire hydrogen which upon arrival, is stripped of their electrons and effectively becomes a [localized proton storm][2]. This could potentially be a massive threat to missiles by irradiating them before they even enter terminal trajectory, frying their guidance package, thus massively reducing their threat. Even if irradiating does not work because the humans equipped their missiles with tons of radiation hardening, you could still switch to firing uranium from the particle beam to get a very damaging beam and physically destroy the missiles.
Nuclear Warheads
In the 1980s, one of the projects being examined by the Strategic Defence Initiative is [Project Excalibur][3], utilizing nuclear bombs to pump x-ray lasers to shoot soviet ICBMs. As the project itself is already designed for shooting missiles, it's point defence applications are obvious. It's design have a energy intensity that might be defeated with armoring, but you could potentially get around that by having more laser rods. Causative have also raised a point regarding how you may want to simply nuke the missiles if the excalibur does not scale well. It's addition to your von newmann fleet not only gives a effective point defence weapon, but also one that is tactically interesting. Does the fleet commander decide to launch the nukes immediately alongside with the kinetic missiles in a alpha strike, or does he use the nukes defensively in order to nuke incoming missiles?
Interceptor drones
Generally, missile designers try to focus their armor on the front (if they included any to start with), so it might make the target's point defence work really hard for any successful intercepts. To circumvent that, what you need is a swarm of drones around the protected vessel. Once a missile is detected, the drones attempt to intercept them either using their own lasers or by using a mirror to reflect the protected vessel's defensive lasers. From a in universe perspective this means that the point defence systems of the target can now hit missiles from the side, both increasing chances of deflection through ablation, and allowing the laser to bypass most of the armor. In the face of this the designers may either distribute the armor to protect it's flanks, which would make it more vulnerable to a direct hit in the front, or try shooting the interceptors first, which reduces the missiles available for actually hitting the ship. However, this scheme truely shines from the authors perspective, as not only does it justify having a "Fleet carrier" equipped with entire wings of interceptors to protect friendly vessels, it also made battles so much more interesting as now commanders are forced to decide on questions like: How many missiles try attacking the interceptors? Try a decapitation strike on the carrier or not? Are the enemy interceptors going to be focused on my intended direction of attack? All these decisions make battles much more interesting than simple missile exchanges.
[1]: https://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php#laserthermal
[2]: https://toughsf.blogspot.com/2018/12/particle-beams-in-space.html
[3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Excalibur

Project Excalibur (lasers) is different from nuclear shaped charges. Nuclear shaped charges are where you try to direct part of the explosion to emit a beam of plasma in a certain direction. This beam cannot be tightly focused - IIRC it's on the order of 15 degrees of spread. And also it only works with low-yield nukes; thermonuclear weapons can't really be shaped. So you might as well just go with the thermonuclear weapon instead of the low-yield shaped charge, unless there are friendlies in range.

I don't know how well Project Excalibur could scale to larger yields. Wikipedia says 3 kJ/cm^2 was their goal energy to destroy ICBMs, which would be completely inadequate to penetrate a missile equipped with a meter or two of steel armor. I think to increase that amount you'd just have to add more and more lasers.

@causative having a meter or two of armor seems a bit too high for the missile the OP described, which is 5 meter long and stated to be barely armored, relying on dodging which is not going to work against a laser, thus it seems to be the textbook example for a laser target. On the other hand you seem right about the scaling part so I’ll go rewrite it once I get my VPN working again.

@causative I finished fixing what you pointed out about scaling and energy intensity, is there any issues remaining?

Well, I'm not so sure about your interceptor drones having standard (non-nuke-pumped) lasers of their own. Lasers useful against even minimal armor are big and heavy, weighing a lot more than the thing they're meant to kill. Having the drone reflecting a laser from the mothership would require a very big reflector as well (otherwise the reflector would simply be destroyed instead of working), and a big reflector would be vulnerable to enemy lasers and other weapons. But giving the drones nuke-pumped lasers, to be fired at the side of the enemy missile as they pass, sounds like a good idea!

About the lack of armor on the missiles: if I were on the side launching missiles, and if I found out the enemy has a laser capable of cutting through the few cm of armor my missiles have, then adding more armor seems like a no brainer. If you have the laser you can expect the enemy to have a countermeasure, if the countermeasure is as simple as that. Unless they get surprised, of course, but that only lasts for a few engagements.

@causative about the problem with reflectors being too bulky. Since the OP's missile is some 5m in length, the Ukrainian R-360 Neptune is 5.05m long so I'm using it's dimensions as a stand-in, and in this case it's diameter is only 38cm, so one side of the missile could have 19cm of armor at most.  If the beam is as wide as the missile and trying to melt it's way through 19cm of steel then extrapolating from the 120GJ for 2m^3 it should only need 1.2GJ for the 0.02m^3 here.  Recycling the 100sec interception time you used above, a 50MW reflector can throw 5GJ at the missile which would suffice

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
